# Session fixation in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, adfs

We are trying to prevent session fixation attack in our application. This means we are expected to generate new `JSESSIONID` every time a user logs into application.

Current scenario doesn't generate new `JSESSIONID` post authentication with ADFS (Active directory). Thus we would like to achieve the same. Can you let us know, how to achieve solution for this kind of attack?

We have Spring, Primefaces and Spring Security used in our application. We tried implementing below tags in our Spring `security.xml file`. However, it doesnt seem to generate new `JSESSIONID` post authentication is successful with ADFS. This `spring-security.xml` has been added in `web.xml`. Can you let us know what is wrong with below use? We are using Spring Security 3.2.10 in project.

```xml
<sec:http create-session="always" use-expressions="true">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/*" />
        <sec:http-basic />
        <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/"
            session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="150"
                expired-url="/" />
        </sec:session-management>
        <sec:csrf/>
    </sec:http>
    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:user-service>
                <sec:user name="abc" password="abc" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </sec:user-service>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: you can see that in any browser in cookies tab. This tab will show its changed value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `Basic` authentication for API, you'd better not create new session

```
<sec:http create-session="stateless" ....
```

If you want to create new session post authentication, the default `Basic` Filter is not supported, but you can implement your own filter and just like `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, there is `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` in it, and [`SessionFixationProtectionStrategy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.html) will create a new session with exist attributes in old session post authentication.

Comment: How to implement SessionAuthenticationStrategy ? Didnt get your solution quite clearly. Could you kindly rephrase again?

Answer (score 0):

I suposse you are using form-login because talking about users login in. Spring includes out-of-the-box session fixation protection. In SessionManagementFilter, in doFilter method, you can see that if the user has been authenticated in the current request, the session authentication strategy is called. This strategy by default is SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.
Apparently your configuration is correct, debug that method and check what is happening. Besides, login forms are recommended to be light and sessionless if possible, so default create-session value "IfRequired" should be preferred instead of "always". Anyway newSession strategy should invalidate current session, ceate a new one and return a new JSESSIONID cookie.